# C++ string manipulation, string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, visual-studio, string, visual-c++

Basically what this should do:

1) gets string and finds its length

2) goes throught all elements in `key` and puts all unique members in start (playfair cipher)

```
Table::Table(string key) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if(start.find(key[i]) == string::npos) { //start is empty string
            start[start.length()] = key[i]; // this line gives error
        }
    }
}
```

error:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the valid indices range from `0` up to `length - 1` inclusive. If you want to add a char to the string, use push_back

```
start.push_back(key[i]); //this will increase the length by 1
```

Comment: Oh yeah, the push_back, had forgotten all about it.

Answer (score 1):

> goes throught all elements in key and puts all unique members in start (playfair cipher)

You should better be using `std::set<char>`. And instead of finding the characters yourself, just use `set::insert` method.

Later just use `std::copy` to copy the contents of `set` to `string`.

Answer (score -1):

The offending line should be

```
start[start.length() - 1] = key[i];
```

String indices go from 0 to (length() - 1).

Comment: No, it shouldn't, it should be `push_back`

Comment: Well when length is 0 as it is in the start, then i would try to add element to position `-1` ?! I think you're wrong Brett.